# Database design for images

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-connection, database-schema

I'm designing my database structure and I need some advice:
I have images that can be selected from categories and others can be uploaded and for every buddy I should save what image was selected...

I have several options:

1. I can put the uploaded images and the predefined images into the same table and put a flag to differentiate between them, and I know that using flags might be risky..
2. I can put the uploaded images and the predefined images into 2 different tables but in that case if I need to put the id of the image selected in the buddy table I will not be able to know from which table this id was given (because the image id is an incremented integer)

so how can I design this? and which method is better and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make these assumptions:

- You have a table with predefined images. Every image has an id.
- A user can upload his own image. An uploaded image can only be used by this user.
- Every user can only upload one image.

In this case, you should define two columns in your buddy table, *image* and *imageID*.
Define default values for these columns, NULL for *image*, and 1 for *imageID*.
Define a referential integrity constraint between *imageID* and the predefined_images table.

Your program should load the image specified in *imageID* if the *image* column is NULL.

For example:

```
SELECT COALESCE( b.image, p.imagedata )
FROM buddy b, predefined_images p 
WHERE b.imageID = p.ID
```